# Hashicorp Vault container don't save my secrets on local volume when I restart docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault, vault

To be brief I'm struggling persisting the data saved in a vault container in my local machine after I put a `docker-compose down` and re-deploy it with `docker-compose up -d`, the data is lost. I'll show you how my `.yml` looks like very simple:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  vault_dev:
      image: vault:latest
      volumes:
        - vault-file:/vault/file
      ports:
        - "8200:8200/tcp"
      environment:
        VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: 'root'
        VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:8200'
      cap_add:
        - IPC_LOCK
      container_name: vault_dev
      entrypoint: "vault server -dev"

volumes:
     vault-file: {}
```

Comment: Is anything interesting in `docker-compose logs vault_dev`?  (I'm fairly sure [`vault server -dev`](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/server#dev) is in-memory only and never persists anything, and I remember it printing a fairly prominent warning message on startup.)

Comment: Yes, thank you david. It was for the dev version, now I deploy it in prod and data persist. c:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Vault is started with the `-dev` option it stores secrets in memory only. They are lost when it shuts down. Nothing to do with Docker.

You probably want to remove the `-dev` option in your Dockerfile entrypoint and [use `file` storage option](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/filesystem) in your configuration file.

Answer (score 5):

Using production Vault server in docker-compose for local development is *not* convenient, because you have to unseal it often, typically every time the container is restarted.

I find it much easier to use the Vault *dev* server mode with one additional bootstrapping container that is initializing the Vault state as I need it.

Here's how to do it. First define the Vault Dev Server in compose.

- It is automatically unsealed
- It has Vault UI accessible at `http://localhost:8200/ui/vault` from your dev machine
- It has predefined root token with value "root", that can be given to services which need to communicate with the Vault

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
vault:
    hostname: vault
    container_name: vault
    image: vault:1.12.0
    environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
      VAULT_API_ADDR: "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/vault/file:/vault/file:rw
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    entrypoint: vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200" -dev-root-token-id="root"
```

Now the Vault is ready for use but it's empty - no keys or additional secret engines are enabled. To fill it with the necessary data I use a second container which is started just once and is enabling/creating the engines/keys which will be used during my work.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  vault-init:
    container_name: vault-init
    image: vault:1.12.0
    volumes:
      - ./vault-init.sh:/vault-init.sh
    depends_on:
      - vault
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: sh -c "/vault-init.sh"
```

This container is executing a `vault-init.sh` script which I have prepared in a directory (in this example it's the same dir as the docker-compose file, but you can place it in another and change the mount path). The script is making the following steps:

- login to Vault
- enable Vault transit engine
- create two keys inside the engine with specific names and types

```bash
#! /bin/sh

set -e

export VAULT_ADDR=http://vault:8200

# give some time for Vault to start and be ready
sleep 3

# login with root token at $VAULT_ADDR
vault login root

# enable vault transit engine
vault secrets enable transit

# create key1 with type ed25519
vault write -f transit/keys/key1 type=ed25519

# create key2 with type ecdsa-p256
vault write -f transit/keys/key2 type=ecdsa-p256
```

After you start it with `docker-compose up -d` you can open the Vault UI with a browser and verify that the Vault is in the state that you desire: `http://localhost:8200/ui/vault`